# Grade F on Add Expires headers

Tags: http, header, http-headers

I used the YSlow Firefox add-on and it return the follow result:

**Grade F on Add Expires headers**

There are 8 static components without a far-future expiration date.

```
* (no expires) http://localhost:63808/WebSite/css/Global.css?...
* (no expires) http://localhost:63808/WebSite/css/BemVindo.css?...
* (no expires) http://localhost:63808/WebSite/js/Global.js?...
* (no expires) http://localhost:63808/WebSite/js/BemVindo.js?...
* (no expires) http://www.maplist.com.br/img/faixa_verde.png
* (no expires) http://www.maplist.com.br/img/logo_home.png
* (no expires) http://www.maplist.com.br/img/wait_bar.gif
* (2010/1/23) http://localhost:63808/WebSite/favicon.ico
```

I resolve the problem using a HttpHandler component:

```
www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/CssAndJavaScriptOptimizer.aspx
```

Is there a easier way to resolve the problem? Maybe in global.asax?

By the way, I'm using this metas in my page:

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="PUBLIC"> 
<META HTTP-EQUIV="EXPIRES" CONTENT="Mon, 22 Jul 2010 11:12:01 GMT">
```

Comment: In the future questions like this, please mention that you're using IIS which you don't have admin control over. This is a very important fact. This will avoid lot of noisy answers. This is already the 2nd time.

Answer (score 3):

You have to change the `Expires:` header of these pages to make them expire in the far future,  allowing user browsers to cache them.

You can use [mod_expires](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_expires.html) in apache, or [this technique](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/apache-speed-expires.html). [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/CachingImagesInASPNET.aspx) is an article explaining how to do it with IIS.

Comment: then how do you answer his question ? without knowing the server technology, that's pretty much everything I can tell him.

Comment: Link him info on how to do it on the two most popular servers, like Apache or IIS.

Comment: I don't have server access, I have to do this in code. I'm trying to do this using a HttpHanlder, but I think that may have a easier way to do this. By the way, I'm using this metas in my page:<META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="PUBLIC">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="EXPIRES" CONTENT="Mon, 22 Jul 2010 11:12:01 GMT">

Comment: I resolve the problem using a HttpHandler component:

www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/CssAndJavaScriptOptimizer.aspx
Is there a easier way to resolve the problem? Maybe in global.asax?

Answer (score 2):

Set it in HTTP header is the most simple solution
But, in my case I turn off PHP/server scripting engine running on pure nginx server and content is push through ftp (from backend-engine)

Comment: If you like me, on a share hosting and static content. maybe you can try modify the .htaccess , check this out -> http://www.xpertdeveloper.com/2011/08/set-expire-headers-using-htaccess/

Answer (score 0):

IIS allows you to set the Expires header automatically on all static content served.  This is the method that I typically use.

Comment: I believe Apache has the same ability.  But I am much less versed in it than IIS.